# Is there anyway in PHPExcel to hide values in an export?

Tags: export, phpexcel, xlsx

I would like to be able to get the ID of my record in my sql statement:

```
$result = $db->query("select id,FQDN, ip_address, .....");
```

However, I don't want it to show up in the export using headings:

```
$headings = array('Name (FQDN)','Management IP Address', ......");
```

Is it possible to hide the ID value?
Thanks

Answer (score 28):

Columns or rows can be set to "HIDDEN"

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setVisible(false);
```

will hide column C

or

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(5)->setVisible(false);
```

will hide row 5

Comment: Perfect! :) Much helpful :)